# Is it possible to share a link to facebook page when clicking a link?

Tags: php, jquery, html, facebook

is it possible to share a link on Facebook page not in Facebook account timeline when clicking a link? All codes i saw in forum are sharing code to account timeline.

Comment: Sorry @Jithesh KK are you able to make your question a little clearer. maybe with an example

Comment: Your app must be allowed by the page itself not only by the admin account I think, not sure though never tried ;)

Comment: I think, sharing a link/post can be possible on Account not on Company's Page.

Comment: I have a Facebook page i wants to share some contents from my website to Facebook page when i clicking share button in my website. @JasonJoslin

Comment: Yes when you share a post you have to share it to your accounts wall/timeline. there is no other way as the share must belong to someone.

Comment: Thanks @JasonJoslin